# How to deploy a DAML to AWS QLDB?

Tags: daml

I want to deploy DAML to QLDB. I've read the documentation and issues, but it doesn't write how to deploy to QLDB.

I read this blog, Can't I still use DAML on QLDB?
https://blog.daml.com/daml-driven/quantum-daml-amazon-qldb-goes-ga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blockchain Technology Partners have documentation how to deploy DAML to QLDB here: https://blockchaintp.com/sextant/daml/getting-started/#daml-on-qldb

Comment: BTP also presented this at a recent DAML Meetup. The deployment process of DAML to QLDB is demoed in the recording from about minute 49. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLkfokA9Kbs